# How to access container IP from host

Tags: docker, networking

Let's say I have a `docker` container running a web application on port 8080.

I have not mapped the ports (at `docker run` did not do `-p 8080:8080`)

Container's IP is 172.17.0.2

why can't I see the application on my host's browser if I do 172.17.0.2:8080 ??

What would I have to do to achieve it?

P.S, I know how to use host network and how to do port mapping and view the web application on localhost:8080, but I don't want to do that.

I want to be able to see < container IP >:< container port > on the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

The container-internal IP addresses are more of an implementation detail than anything else.  In many contexts (from MacOS hosts; on Docker Toolbox; from other hosts) they’re unreachable.

You don’t ever need to look up the container-internal IP addresses, and really shouldn’t.  The right way to access your container is to delete it and restart it with an appropriate `docker run -p` option, and then it will be reachable via the host’s IP address and the port you chose.

(Say you run the same process outside of a Docker container.  What is that *process’s* IP address?)

Comment: I know its not the right way, I just want to do this out of curiosity. I am on mac though.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the Gateway of the container instead of the IP of the container. Instead `https://localhost:8080` do
`172.17.0.X:8080` without `https://`. This works for me.

Comment: Didnt work for me. If it is of any use, I am on mac.